# Vue, Vue-chartjs, pass looped data from template to script tag

Tags: vue.js, web, chart.js, vue-chartjs

I am totally new to Vuejs and I used vue-chartjs.
So I am calling data from an API to a parent view and passing it into a component.
It generates charts based on how much chart I have which is good. However I can't figure how to change "chartData"'s data based on what I got from the API.
using: vue3 composition API and vue-chartjs

**viewChart.vue**

```js
<template>
    <div class="grid grid-rows-2 grid-flow-col gap-40">
        <chart :charts="charts"/>        
    </div>
</template>
  
<script setup>

    import chart from '../components/chart.vue'
    import axios from 'axios'
    import { nextTick, ref, reactive } from 'vue';

    const charts = ref([])


    const getCharts = async () => {
        
        try {
         
        const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/charts/',{
            headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            }
        })
            charts.value = response.data
            console.log(charts.notApplicable)
               
        } catch (error) {
            
        }
    }
getCharts()
</script>
```

**chart.vue**

```js
<template>

<div style="color:black;">
<h2 class="text-black">Title</h2>
<div v-for="chart in charts" :key="chart.id">
<!-- {{chart.chart}} -->
<Pie 
      :chart-options="chartOptions"
      :chart-data="chartData"
      :chart-id="chartId"
      :dataset-id-key="datasetIdKey"
      :plugins="plugins"
      :css-classes="cssClasses"
      :styles="styles"
      :width="width"
      :height="height"
    />
</div>

</div>
</template>

<script setup>


    import { ref, reactive, watch } from 'vue'
    import { Pie } from  'vue-chartjs'
    import { Chart as ChartJS, Title, Tooltip, Legend, ArcElement, CategoryScale } from 'chart.js'

    ChartJS.register(Title, Tooltip, Legend, ArcElement, CategoryScale)

    
    const props = defineProps({
        chartId:{
            type: String,
            default: 'pie-chart' 
        },
        datasetIdKey:{
            type: String,
            default: 'label'
        },
        width: {
            type: Number,
            default: 300
        },
        height: {
            type: Number,
            default: 500
        },
        cssClasses: {
            default: '',
            type: String
        },
        styles: {
            type: Object,
            default: () => {}
        },
        plugins: {
            type: Object,
            default: () => {}
        },
        charts: {
            type: Object,
            default: () => {}
        }
    })

    /* data */

    const chartData = reactive({
        labels: [ 'Implemented', 
        'Partically Implemented', 
        'Not Implemented',
        'Not Applicable' ],
        datasets: [ { 
            backgroundColor: [ 'Green', 'Orange', 'Red', 'Grey'],
            data: [ 4,2,8,5] 
        } ]
    })
    
    const chartOptions = reactive({
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        plugins:{
            legend:{
                display:true,
                position:'bottom',
            }
        }
    })


    
</script>
```

tried watchers and emits based on what I saw on the internet but I do not actually get it

Answer (score -1):

try putting you api request into a [onMounted](https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-lifecycle.html#onmounted) hook

```js
import { onMounted } from 'vue'

async function getCharts() {
 try {
         
        const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/charts/',{
            headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            }
        })
            charts.value = response.data
            console.log(charts.notApplicable)
               
        } catch (error) {
            
        }
}

onMounted(() => {
  getCharts() //<--------------- call your API here.
})
```

---

#### Update

```js
const chartData = computed(() => {
  return {
    labels: [
      'Implemented',
      'Partically Implemented',
      'Not Implemented',
      'Not Applicable',
    ],
    datasets: [
      {
        backgroundColor: ['Green', 'Orange', 'Red', 'Grey'],
        data: props.charts.data, // ??? how does your response look like?
      },
    ],
  };
})
```

otherwise give me a model example of your chart api response

Comment: I am not sure this what I want. my question is I want the data from API to be passed into datasets' data

Comment: The response will look like { "id":1, "chart": "year of 2022", "implemented":2...etc}. The issue I am facing that I am looping through the array from <template> as you can see above and I wanna know how to loop through the dataset's data to inject the data from API to dataset's array